# Drawing a dome in Google Earth with KML

Tags: kml, google-earth

I need to draw a dome symbolizing the edge of radar detection capabilities in Google Earth (GE), but am finding it difficult. As it stands, I have not found any useful tools to draw even circles in GE. I'd be much obliged if anyone could help.

Comment: Maybe create an outsized 3D building?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I got a circle by using the Vincenty equations, and then drew lines crossing the circle, all going through the center, using great circle calculations. Then I added height to those lines at different fractional lengths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw a circle by using the Vincenty equations with inputs of lat1/2,lon1/2, and then draw lines crossing the circle, all going through the center, using great circle calculations(midpoints, etc.). Then, add height to those lines at different fractional lengths.

Comment: Can you add additional context for your statement: "at different fractional lengths?"

Answer (score 0):

I, too, created a circle using Vincenty.  However, I stacked concentric circle polygons atop one another.  The tricky bit was calculating where the points of the circles would be beyond the first that was laid out on the ground.

Check out this page for the equation and a lot of explanation: https://www.liutaiomottola.com/formulae/sag.htm.  The long and short of the solution was in calculating the sagitta, then calculating the height of the sagitta given an offset from center.

In my solution, I could safely assume my dome was actually just a semi-circle (perfect).  So the sagitta equation broke down to: `s = radius` and calculating the height (*h*) from offset (*x*) became: `h = squareRoot(radius^2 - x^2)`

So my concentric circles shrank by one kilometer each time, so offset because `radius - 1`.

I wrote a simple python script to output all the coordinates and altitudes.  I used 5-degree bearing shifts to get all the points.  I could have done 1-degree but the size of the KML started to get a little too large for my taste.